# Proper way to cancel animation for other items

Tags: android, animation

I have a container (GridLayout) in which I place multiple views. When I click on any of these views, an infinite animation should be applied (to indicate that it's the selected/chosen view).

The problem is that I need to clear the previous animation so there's only one animation playing at a time (for the view that's clicked).

I was thinking to have a global definition of animation and then simply cancel it onClick and assign a new View to it, but the ObjectAnimator has no method to cancel it.

```
GridLayout container = (GridLayout) filterPackContainer.findViewById( R.id.container );   

for( int f=0; f<10; f++ )
{
    View child = that.getLayoutInflater().inflate( R.layout.child, null );

    child.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            ObjectAnimator anim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat( v, "alpha", .5f, 1f );
            anim.setDuration( 1000 );
            anim.setRepeatMode( 2 );
            anim.setRepeatCount( 999999 );
            anim.start();
        }
    });

    container.addView( child );
}
```

Then I tried to save the View as reference inClick, and cancel any existing animations using clearAnimation(), but this has no effect and the animation just keeps playing.

```
View vRef = null;

---------------------

GridLayout container = (GridLayout) filterPackContainer.findViewById( R.id.container );   

for( int f=0; f<10; f++ )
{
    View child = that.getLayoutInflater().inflate( R.layout.child, null );

    child.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            if( vRef != null )
                vRef.clearAnimation();

            vRef = v;

            ObjectAnimator anim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat( v, "alpha", .5f, 1f );

            anim.setDuration( 1000 );
            anim.setRepeatMode( 2 );
            anim.setRepeatCount( 999999 );
            anim.start();
        }
    });

    container.addView( child );
}
```

any hints on how to handle this properly? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [AnimatorSet](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/AnimatorSet) to control your animations.

> This class plays a set of Animator objects in the specified order. Animations can be set up to play together, in sequence, or after a specified delay.
>
> There are two different approaches to adding animations to a AnimatorSet: either the playTogether() or playSequentially() methods can be called to add a set of animations all at once, or the play(Animator) can be used in conjunction with methods in the Builder class to add animations one by one.

```
         AnimatorSet animatorSet = new AnimatorSet();
                 
         child.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                if(animatorSet.isRunning)
                   animatorSet.cancel();
                   
                   
                ObjectAnimator anim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat( v, "alpha", .5f, 1f );
                anim.setDuration( 1000 );
                anim.setRepeatMode( 2 );
                anim.setRepeatCount( 999999 );
                                
                AnimatorSet animatorSet = new AnimatorSet();
                animatorSet.playTogether(anim);
                animatorSet.start();
            }
        });
```